# Directive that remembers its state between route changes?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I would like my directive to store the time it was last clicked and remember that through route/view changes.

Normally this is easy, since a directive usually displays data from a model that is persistent. I am happy to do this, but without an ID or something, I don't know how to retrieve the time for the correct directive.

In other words I would like to be able to do this:

```
<clicktime>Last Clicked:</clicktime>
<clicktime>Last Clicked:</clicktime>
```

But the only way I can think of doing it is by giving each directive instance a unique id, and using that to store the time it was last clicked (in a service). Something like this:

```
//html
<clicktime myID="c1">Last Clicked:</clicktime>
<clicktime myID="c2">Last Clicked:</clicktime>

//directive
template: '<div><button href="#" ng-click="click()" class="button">
           <span ng-transclude></span> {{clicked}}</button></div>',
link: function(scope, element){

   //Use the myID to retrieve the last clicked time from a service
   scope.clicked = scope.getLastClicked(attrs.myID);

   scope.click = function(){
     var now = new Date();
     scope.clicked = now;
     //store the last clicked time
     scope.setLastClicked(attrs.myID, now);
   }
}
```

Requiring manually assigned IDs is bad, but I don't know how to avoid it.

Here is a plunker of the problem. I would like the time to be remembered if you click a button, click another page, then click back to home.

http://plnkr.co/edit/c8ZPNDWv8HuXbpzavTSq?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

This solution does keep the manually assigned ids, but unless the data needs to be shared with other parts of the app, or survive full-page refreshes, I would probably avoid a service, and for simplicity just use a simple cache object inside the directive definition:

```
myApp.directive('clicktime', function(){
  cache = [];
  return {
    transclude:true,
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: true,
    template: '<div><button href="#" ng-click="click()" class="button"><span ng-transclude></span> {{clicked}}</button></div>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
      scope.clicked = cache[attrs.clicktimeId] || 'never';
      scope.click = function(){
        cache[attrs.clicktimeId] = new Date();
        scope.clicked = cache[attrs.clicktimeId];
      };
    }
  };
});
```

used as

```
<clicktime clicktime-id="1">Last Clicked: </clicktime>
```

which can be seen working at http://plnkr.co/edit/B7B0SLAZLXHezYrbCIIx?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

If you have at most one of the directives per route (which admittedly your question suggests isn't the case), and are prepared to use `ui-router`, you can use the state name as the ID for the directive, accessed by `$state.current.name`:

```
myApp.directive('clicktime', function($state){
  cache = [];
  return {
    transclude:true,
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: true,
    template: '<div><button href="#" ng-click="click()" class="button"><span ng-transclude></span> {{clicked}}</button></div>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
      var id = $state.current.name;
      scope.clicked = cache[id] || 'never';
      scope.click = function(){
        cache[id] = new Date();
        scope.clicked = cache[id];
      };
    } 
  };
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This solution occurred to me, but yeah, there will be more than one directive per route. I was going to use $location.path() instead of ui-router. Your other solution works, I just really didn't want to have to manually assign ids. It looks messy and there is the burden of keeping them unique over many pages. Might have to do it though.

Comment: @Zee You could always use combination of path/state name and an id on the element that is just local to that route. This would reduce the burden a fair bit.